# CSV -> textConnection -> R: parsing problems

Tags: regex, r, parsing, csv, import

I have been looking around for the answer to my problem for over 3 weeks now.

I request you not to sidetrack the discussion.

Problem:
I have a csv file that I need to read into R for further analysis.

I have tried the following methods and all give different number of rows:
read.csv - outputs 1.7 mill rows

```r
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/kavindra.mishra/Desktop/~/RelatedKW.csv",header=T,nrow=-1,strip.white=TRUE,na.strings= c("   "," ", ""))
```

read.table - outputs 180 mill rows

```r
qdata <- read.table("RelatedKW.csv",
                header = T, sep = ",", 
                #quote = "\"",
                #numerals = c("allow.loss"),
                row.names = NULL, 
                col.names = c("Keyword","Product","Subcat","Visits","Order"),
                na.strings = c("   "," ", ""), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                colClasses = c("character","character","character", "numeric", "numeric"),
                #nrows = 1000,
                skip = 1, check.names = TRUE, 
                fill = TRUE, 
                strip.white = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
                comment.char = "",
                allowEscapes = TRUE, flush = FALSE,
                skipNul = TRUE)
```

WHat does the quote = do? No help was helpful enough.

Since both of them were having issues either with the /n character at the end of each row (as in read.csv) or with the comma ',' within quotes ("") being broken into multiple columns (read.table), I tried reading in the data as a text connection.

```r
fileName <- "RelatedKW.csv"
con <- file(fileName,open="r")
line <- readLines(con)
close(con)


line <- gsub("\\n"," \\n ",line)
line <- gsub(" \\n +"," \\n ",line)

line <- gsub('[/\"]{2}',"",line)
line <- gsub('", $',",",line)

line <- gsub('[/\"]','"',line)
line <- gsub('[/\]','',line)

line <- gsub("^\"","",line)
```

I tried cleaning the data with regex. But I have no clue how to read it into an R dataframe!

My final Qs:

How do I read in a csv data file with quotes at both ends of each row, rows separated by '\n' and every character column with quotes at both ends. There are sometimes, quotes within a column

for eg. ""toys" , ""HALLMARK" greeting cards, toys" , "Toys" , "5" , "1"" \n

would be one row of data with all the problems.

How do I read in the data from the regex-cleaned textConnection into R? The output file after the regex looks like this:

```
c("\"Search Keyword (evar66)\",\"Deal Name\",\"Parent_Sub_Category\",\"Visits\",\"Orders\"", 
",,,23473934,50065", ",\"1.50CTW GE, B& WD.925 SSR\",\"Rings\",2,0", 
)
```

*I took head(file,n=2)

Please try to understand that I can't share the data. I can send a snippet if you can tell me how to keep only the first character in each column and discard rest of the words etc (to mask the data).

EDIT:
The solution using perl script does the following

Code:

```
cat RelatedKW.csv | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/|/g' > newRelatedKW.csv
```

Data before code:

```
c("\"Search Keyword (evar66)\",\"Deal Name\",\"Parent_Sub_Category\",\"Visits\",\"Orders\"", 
",,,23473934,50065", ",\"1.50CTW GE, B& WD.925 SSR\",\"Rings\",2,0", 
)
```

Data after edit:

```
c("\"Search Keyword (evar66)|Deal Name|Parent_Sub_Category|Visits|Orders\"", ",,,23473934,50065", ",\"1.50CTW GE, B& WD .925 SSR|R\",2,0", )
```

There are problems with beginning and ending quotes, not all separators are converted to '|'

EDIT 2: 
Explanation of the problem with the perl code:

Thank you for your patience with this problem. The code only replaces the delimiter in the header row properly because "," is the separator. It doesn't do anything to the first row where the first three columns are empty and only last two columns have numbers.. Please see:

```
c("\"Search Keyword (evar66)|Deal Name|Parent_Sub_Category|Visits|Orders\"",     ",,,23473934,50065",)
```

Also the first real row of data behaves as following:

```
",\"1.50CTW GE, B& WD .925 SSR|R\",2,0",
```

The first separator is untouched, the second is replaced by '|' and the 3rd and 4th separators are untouched too.

Do you have a method to include /d into the code? something akin ",\d should be the separator between 2nd and third columns and \d,\d between 3rd and 4th without disturbing the numbers. I don't care about the last column, just FYI.

Comment: in your example ` ""toys" , ""HALLMARK" greeting cards, toys" , "Toys" , "5" , "1"" \n` how many columns should it be ?

Comment: It should be 5 columns, first 3 character and last 2 numeric.!

toys | "HALLMARK" greeting cards, toys | Toys | 5 | 1

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks @alexwlchan for the edit. The Q looks less intimidating now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use perl to clean up your csv. Here is what I did:

```
cat yourfile.csv | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/||/g'
```

What this does is get rid of the quotes that are field separators and the \n in the end and convert the field separators to ||.

Ex. Contents of /tmp/a.csv is:

```
""toys" , ""HALLMARK" greeting cards, toys" , "Toys" , "5" , "1"" \n
""Atoys" , ""AHALLMARK" greeting cards, toys" , "AToys" , "50" , "100"" \n
```

Running the perl on the commandline will give:

```
cat /tmp/a.csv | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/||/g'

toys||"HALLMARK" greeting cards, toys||Toys||5||1 
Atoys||"AHALLMARK" greeting cards, toys||AToys||50||100
```

And then you can give r the fieldseparator as "||"

Comment: Which package should I add to use this command?

I am writing:
data <- cat RelatedKW.csv | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/||/g'

It gives: Error: unexpected symbol in "data <- cat RelatedKW.csv"

Comment: Open up a bash shell and do: cat RelatedKW.csv | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/||/g' > newRelatedKW.csv and then open up R and read in newRelatedKW.csv and give it sep option as ||. Hope that helps.

Comment: The newRelatedKW.csv is new file that is a cleaned up version of the original csv file

Comment: I do not have bash. I am using R Studio on windows 7.

Comment: Can you run perl on windows?

Comment: I have installed Perl Strawberry before as it is required for R packages like WriteXLS to work. I am not sure how to use it as a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks Susan for the help. My colleague has a linux machine and I'd try out this code on that machine. Will keep you posted. I tried using perl from windows cmd by typing 'perl -v'. But when I input the code, It says "String found where operator expected at code.pl line 1 near "pe 's......"

It is not able to use -pe as a command.

Comment: It should work on a linux machine. Good luck. Please choose answer and upvote :). I'll check back later.

Comment: Replacing sep by || wouldn't work for R as the scan() function inherent to all csv reading packages needs one character separator.

Comment: Susan, Could you please explain the code so that I can edit it according to my requirement.

Quotes aren't field separators. Only commas are; quotes are present in a lot of places as explained in the question (see the Main Qs part1).

Comment: Kavindra -  yes, I know. The code takes into consideration all of this. Your field separator is not a comma, it's actually "," with whitespace between the " & comma. The double quotes in the field get preserved. In the answer I gave you will see that the quotes in HALLMARK are preserved when I run my code. Did you try running the code?  If you don't want || as the field separator you can replace it with whatever you want, eg. ^  cat file  | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/^/g'.

Comment: Susan, thank you for your patience with this problem. The code only replaces the delimiter in the header row properly because "," is the separator. It doesn't do anything to the first row where the first three columns are empty and only last two columns have numbers.. 

Please see: c("\"Search Keyword (evar66)|Deal Name|Parent_Sub_Category|Visits|Orders\"", ",,,23473934,50065",)

Also the first real row of data behaves as following:

",\"1.50CTW GE, B& WD .925 SSR|R\",2,0", 

The first separator is untouched, the second is replaced by '|' and the 3rd and 4th separators are untouched too.

Comment: Hey, no problem. This is fun. So from what I gather sometimes the numbers in the fields are in double quotes but sometimes not. It looks like the lines are from R head(). It's a little confusing to trace back from R head to the original csv file. Can you also add just the output of head -2 original.csv file from the command line to the question?

Comment: You can add this pipe to the original perl. cat file.csv | perl -pe 's/(^"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/|/g' |  perl -pe 's/,(\d)/|$1/g'  It looks for leftover commas with digits and replace it with the | & digit. FYI - I would not recommend doing such complicated search/replaces on the command line. I would write a parser. I understood the data to be uniform initially & so attempted on the command line. If you still run into problems please post following from the command line{not R}? Lines from csv with problems. Lines after running cat & perl and what it should be.

Comment: I know it is utterly inappropriate but "I love you, Susann". :D

Comment: I am new to the community and do not have 15 points that are required to upvote. But, I've chosen yours as the correct answer. I'll upvote ASAP. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Susan Eraly:

I had to go through a steep learning phase but PERL is what worked in the end.
I downloaded CygWin ( a bash prompt for windows) and ran the following script that worked beautifully:

$ cat yourfile.csv | perl -pe 's/(^,"|"\s*"|"\s*"\s*\n$)//g' | perl -pe 's/"\s*,\s*\"/|/g' | perl -pe 's/^,"|,,|,(\d)/ |$1/g' > newyourfile.csv

It replaced all the separators that were confusing R and Delimit in proper parsing of the file.

Thank you everyone once more! Cheers. :)